# Unable to get specific element on a page, using xpath for a Selenium script

Tags: selenium, xpath, css-selectors

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8n8r.png)I am having difficulty locating input fields on a form, that has another component embedded.

I can navigate to the beginning of the component, but am unable to locate anything inside the component, using xpath , css location etc...

Even if I inspect the element in chrome, and copy its xpath or css (right click, copy xpath/ selector) and try that path , the element is not found.

There is a #shadow-root element, which I think may be causing the issue ?

See screenshot of where I can locate beginning of component, the selector i am using and the input field i would like to locate

Any ideas/suggestions very welcome

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8n8r.png)

Comment: Can you please share the URL or HTML DOM?

Comment: Its an internal url  im afraid

Comment: You cannot access shadow DOM with regular locators. You need to use javascript to find the element. You can paste that HTML along with question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I now understand what shadow dom is... 
I've never came across it before. now reading up about it...